# SPD 2013 Workflow cancel when using email action

Tags: designer-workflow

I try a basic workflow, just to send email when running the workflow but the workflow cancel with the following error, if I do something else like setting a field value the workflow works, but as soon as I use the send email action, to workflow fail..:

RequestorId: f73b1b38-8400-7156-cb74-174a672caeea. Details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 400 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["92"],"SPRequestGuid":["f73b1b38-8400-7156-cb74-174a672caeea"],"request-id":["f73b1b38-8400-7156-cb74-174a672caeea"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4420"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Sun, 24 Mar 2013 21:01:04 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor

Comment: Hi Martin, please see my answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/142639/4320

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because the email ID not registered to nay of the users in SharePoint. U can register the Email ID by just changing the Email ID of a User to email ID you are using.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevpreview/thread/256cdcfc-56ef-4ba3-a9c8-2f4e91cca230/

[SharePoint 2013 Workflow runtime doesn't work?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61955/sharepoint-2013-workflow-runtime-doesnt-work)

check this links for SPD2013 workflow is always canceled.

Answer (score 0):

This is because SMTP server is down. Go through the below link.
http://designerworkflow.blogspot.in/2014/02/error-requestorid-1ca8de59-3d62-782a.html