# Workflow Suspended at Email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, email

My SharePoint 2013 workflow keeps suspending itself at the point it's supposed to send an email.  The email details have been specified in Central Admin but it's still not working.  When the workflow is supposed to send an email out (internally) it suspends with an error.  Here is the information that is given about the suspension.

> RequestorId: 951f4793-1f5b-7054-0000-000000000000.
>
> Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance.
>
> Exception details:     System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],
>                               "X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["73"],
>                               "SPRequestGuid":["951f4793-1f5b-7054-ab33-e189b0ee0f23"],
>                               "request-id":["951f4793-1f5b-7054-ab33-e189b0ee0f23"],
>                               "X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],
>                               "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4569"],
>                               "X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],
>                               "X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],
>                               "Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],
>                               "Date":["Mon, 19 Jan 2015 14:08:56 GMT"],
>                               "Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],
>                               "X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],
>                               "X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} 
>                                   at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) 
>                                   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, 
>                                       ActivityExecutor executor, 
>                                       BookmarkManager 
>                                       bookmarkManager) 
>                                   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(
>                                       ActivityExecutor executor, 
>                                       BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, 
>                                       Location resultLocation)

Can anyone tell me what could be causing this? I'm not 100% on what this error even means.

Comment: A few things you could check:

- Are you running this wf as system account or normal user who is added to site/list/library?

- If the user is part of a SP group, does that group membership set as everyone?

Comment: Also please check if Require Documents to be Checked out is selected, if it is Yes change it to No and try the workflow again. 
Also try to uncheck the option "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name" in the SPD workflow properties

Answer (score 1):

How do you have the "To" field configured? Is it a lookup? I'm not 100% on that specific error but it's possible the system can't find who to send the email to.

Answer (score 0):

A permissions review **may** resolve this issue.

For our case, we had the following architecture:

```
Securable object        Description               Unique/inherited permissions    
--------------------    ------------------------  ----------------------------
SiteA                   Group home page           Unique
SiteA/SubsiteA          Sensitive group           Inherited
SiteA/SubsiteA/ListA    Sensitive data            Inherited
```

List "SubsiteA/ListA" represented the list associated with our failing workflow.

The root site, "SiteA", had the following permissions, with subsite "SubsiteA" inheriting permissions:

```
Name                Type                Permission Levels   Members
-----------------   ------------------  -----------------   ---------------
SiteA Owners        SharePoint Group    Full Control        "ADomain\ADistributionList"
SiteA All People    SharePoint Group    Contribute          Empty
SiteA Members       SharePoint Group    Edit                Empty
SiteA Visitors      SharePoint Group    Read                "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users"
```

Active Directory distribution list "ADDistributionList1" contained an Active Directory named account of the user editing the list (for example, "ADomain\AUser").

**After adding "ADomain\AUser" to group "SiteA Owners", all workflows began working.**

This indicates a permissions issue may trigger this issue. One thought: I believe SharePoint may require access to the hidden list "Workflow History", accessible via SharePoint Designer > All Files > Lists ([hat tip](http://anujabhojani.blogspot.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-workflow-gets-canceled.html?showComment=1375367275151#c2164301175897648950)). Other issues may exist.