# Custom workflows won't send email on doc lib with event receiver

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, event-receivers, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-email

I've got a ItemAdded even receiver running on a document library, and I just built a simple (send email) workflow in SPDesigner and I'm getting the following error below:

> RequestorId: 21d893a9-49ec-fb66-180b-afa08f57dc78. Details:
>   System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-
>   SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":
>   ["124"],"SPRequestGuid":["db19f9b8-18a2-46d5-b2ce-c1e0caed07ed"],"request-id":["db19f9b8-18a2-46d5-b2ce-c1e0caed07ed"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4719"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Thu,
>   06 Aug 2015 05:58:42
>   GMT"],"Set-Cookie":["WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={a9eb709c-e5a0-4bb1-a1c0-356bc959b57a};
>   path=/"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

I have tested other lists and document libraries within this dev web application and all send emails successfully, I have another identical doc lib in a live environment and that also produces the error.

The ItemAdded event receiver looks like this:

```
   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        EventFiringEnabled = false;
        try
        {
            string url = properties.ListItem.Url;
            if (url.Contains("Strategies"))
            {
                properties.ListItem["ContentType"] = "Strategy";

                properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate(false);

            }
 ---------- code skipped for brevity
 catch { }

        EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }
```

I can only assume that using custom code has caused this error, any help or pointers to a solution would be appreciated!

**Edit**
Thanks for the suggested links regarding similar issues, as far as I can see, these issues are true across the whole site... my issue is list specific, if I've misread the suggested links or misinterpreted them I will revisit, however I am not experiencing any server issues, or authentication issues on any other list or site on the farm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SPD 2013 Workflow cancel when using email action](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62943/spd-2013-workflow-cancel-when-using-email-action)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a question on this:

[SPD 2013 Workflow cancel when using email action](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62943/spd-2013-workflow-cancel-when-using-email-action?rq=1)

It is mainly because if the email id is not valid or concerned user is not valid and not because you had another customer event handler.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think this is the issue, as I'm testing the exact same workflow on different lists it works perfectly fine on all lists except the two that have been modified. Or is it possible that this issue can specifically effect certain lists?