# SharePoint 2013 workflow canceled with a strange error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created a workflow in sharepoint designer 2013. This workflow is a list workflow. When I create a new item in this list, the workflow starts automatically. But I can also start the workflow manually. When the workflow starts and I go to the workflow status, I can see that it is canceled. When I go to the error I see this message:

> RequestorId: a5c1657a-aaa8-640e-b588-cbefd361c14b. Details:
>   System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPRequestGuid":["a5c1657a-aaa8-640e-b588-cbefd361c14b"],"request-id":["a5c1657a-aaa8-640e-b588-cbefd361c14b"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4420"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0,
>   private"],"Date":["Fri, 31 Jan 2014 11:17:27
>   GMT"],"Set-Cookie":["WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={95337939-7514-4a90-952f-54611a074606};
>   path=/"],"WWW-Authenticate":["NTLM"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Does someone know what is going wrong? I created a new workflow with just 1 simple activity. It also gives this error. So it is not something in the workflow.

UPDATE

I logged in on my dev machine with another user (not the farm admin). Now I got another error (http 500). When I change the workflow with some activity which is changing some column value in the list item it works fine without any errors. When I add an email activity I got this 500 error.

RequestorId: a0caad2f-0745-2d96-327a-071967e2548d. Details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["319"],"SPRequestGuid":["a0caad2f-0745-2d96-327a-071967e2548d"],"request-id":["a0caad2f-0745-2d96-327a-071967e2548d"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4420"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Fri, 31 Jan 2014 15:13:28 GMT"],"Set-Cookie":["WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={95337939-7514-4a90-952f-54611a074606}; path=/"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem

ps. I have check the user profile service application and did a full sync. It doesnt help.

Comment: HTTP 401 means Unauthorized. It might be something related to missing or wrong authorization. By the way, this question has already been asked here. See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61955/sharepoint-2013-workflow-runtime-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

If you know the user's permission is correct, verify that the permissions are given in groups AD.

The Workflow 2013 will not work with users who are granted permission through AD groups, SharePoint groups only. In groups of sharepoint you must give permission to each user. Or, you can give permission to the direct user in the list or site in question.

I've had a similar problem and this solved.